# How do I convert a string, full of words in their own lines, into an array?

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, words

I have a string full of quite a lot of words, one on each line, like this:

```
CAT
DOG
BIRD
```

How do I convert this into an array in which all of the words are separated by a space before and after them, like this;

```
[ CAT , DOG , BIRD ]
```

I need to use this as a list.

Comment: Why do you want to add spaces around the words?

Comment: Do you need an array of strings like `" CAT "`, or a string with the format `[ CAT , DOG , BIRD ]`?

Comment: To answer Michael Foukarakis, I need an array of strings. Also, to answer Rohan Amrute, I need spaces around the words because I am checking whether certain words are in a sentence, but the text file with all the words I'm checking for has one word on each line.

Answer (score 1):

Simply split each line with `split()` or `splitlines()`:

```
>>> s = '''CAT
... DOG
... BIRD'''
>>> s.split()
['CAT', 'DOG', 'BIRD']
>>> s.splitlines()
['CAT', 'DOG', 'BIRD']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 'CAT\nBIRD\nDOG'
s_array = s.split('\n')

print s_array
>> ['CAT', 'BIRD', 'DOG']
```

Answer (score 0):

`split()` and add spaces to the both end.

```
s = '''CAT 
DOG 
BIRD'''

print [' '+i+' ' for i in s.split()]
[' CAT ', ' DOG ', ' BIRD ']
```

Comment: Thanks - I think your answer is the one I'll go for.

Answer (score 0):

Your String is like this

```
CAT
DOG
BIRD
```

In python your string is like "CAT\nDOG\nBIRD"

so in order to make this a list simply split it by line:

```
string = "CAT\nDOG\nBIRD"
list = string.split("\n")
```

Note: I also liked splitlines() As TigerHawk said

Answer (score 0):

[str.split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

```
line = "CAT DOG BIRD"
words = []

words.append(line.split())
```

Output:

```
>>> words
[['cat', 'dog', 'bird']]
```

Answer (score 0):

As other mentioned after splitting you get an array

```
s = 'CAT\nBIRD\nDOG'
s_array = s.split('\n')
```

So,

```
s_array=['CAT','BIRD','DOG']

spaced_s_array=map(lambda x: ' ' + x+ ' ',s_array)
>>> spaced_s_array
[' CAT ', ' BIRD ', ' DOG ']
```

after applying lambda function to each element in s_array gives spaced_s_array